# On change of dropdown how will I redirect to another URL

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="myservlet.do" method="POST">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option>
       <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

> When I select Two, I want to redirect it another form

What would be the perfect solution using javascript?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the value of `action` attribute before submit?

Comment: Forget about onchange event for a while. Assume it's not in the place as of now. I want to redirect the second option using form tag

Answer (score 1):

You can define js like this to achieve that.

```
function changeEvent() {
        var selectedVal = document.getElementById("myselect").value;
        if (selectedVal === "2") {
            window.location.href = 'http://testurl.com';
            return false;
        }
}     

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="changeEvent()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
</form>
```